# VBA - sum if rows hidden below

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am making a org chart with values attached at each level. I already have a simple hide rows VBA. How can I add on to it so that for example

if the value of Company A (e.g. J11) = values of Companies 1, 2, and 3, which are displayed in H14, J14, and L14

then when row 14 is hidden, then J11= sum(H14, J14, L14)

and when row 14 is visible, then J11 = 0

This is what i have so far just to hide/unhide rows.

```
Sub sbHideAll()

Rows("10:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

```
Sub sbShowAll()

Call sbHideAll

Rows("10:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

```
Sub sbShowGUCL()

Call sbHideAll

Rows("10:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Post your current code, so we can work from there

Comment: Curious - in `sbShowAll()` why even hide rows 10-25, just to unhide them? What's the purpose of that call? The `SUM()` part would just be to loop through cells, and if that cell is hidden, sum the others (among other ways to do it). What have you tried on that part?

Comment: The 10-25 hide is a bit preemptive, because here are several more layers below companies 1-3 - so eventually i'm just going to replicate this formula for each layer, below.

Comment: You can use `AGGREGATE` to sum values while ignoring hidden rows

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly but you can get the value of the visible cells.

So take the value of the range like this:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Union(Range("H13:H100"), Range("J13:J100"), Range("L13:L100")))
```

then take the value of the visible cells using `.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` like this:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Union(Range("H13:H100").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Range("J13:J100").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Range("L13:L100").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)))
```

Then minus one from the other

You can either assign each to a variable or just plop it straight into J11 like so:

```
Range("J11").Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Union(Range("H13:H100"), Range("J13:J100"), Range("L13:L100"))) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Union(Range("H13:H100").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Range("J13:J100").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Range("L13:L100").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)))
```